# Can I retrieve documents from specific public folder on Google Drive with Google Drive iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

In my iOS app, how can I list all documents in a specific public folder on Google Drive?  Or sign-in to a specific user and shows all documents of the user from a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the query in the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it) method?

you can put:  `'<folder Id>' in parents`  in the query parameter
and then you'll get the files contained in that folder.

Comment: how to get id of folder?

Comment: On the Drive UI, when you open a folder, the url will contain the folderID similar to this: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/<Folder ID>.